# I need to merge multiple .csv files together side by side with unequal number of rows

Tags: awk, cut, csv-simple, paste

I have anywhere from 3-5 .csv files and need to be able to merge them together while keeping everything in its respective columns below is an easy example with files with varying number of rows. file1 file2 file3 file4 file5 > finalfile.

File 1

```
1 1  
1 1  
1 1
```

File 2

```
2 2 2     
2 2 2
```

File 3

```
3  
3  
3  
3
```

File 4

```
4  
4
```

File 5

```
5  
5  
5  
5  
5
```

I need the results in .csv file to merge all of the files together and keep everything in their respective columns. The 0's are blank cells/columns in my example.

Final File

```
1 1 2 2 2 3 4 5       
1 1 2 2 2 3 4 5   
1 1 0 0 0 3 0 5    
0 0 0 0 0 3 0 5  
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5
```

Everything I have currently tried will slide everything over to the left if there is no data in those cells/columns.

Final File

```
1 1 2 2 2 3 4 5  
1 1 2 2 2 3 4 5   
1 1 3 5  
3 5  
5
```

Comment: Find the shapes and then reshape so that they uniform and are padded with 0's.

Answer (score 1):

Using `csvkit` with no header `-H` and disable inference `-I` (otherwise values of `1` are interpreted as `TRUE`

```
csvjoin -H -I file*
```

gets you this far (with a few error messages because there are no headers so it complains and adds some)

```
a,b,a2,b2,c,a2_2,a2_3,a2_4
1,1,2,2,2,3,4,5
1,1,2,2,2,3,4,5
1,1,,,,3,,5
,,,,,3,,5
,,,,,,,5
```

How you go from there to replace the missing values and lose the delimiter is a matter of taste but you can iterate over the fields in `awk`, setting the delimiter to `-F","`,  skipping the headers `NR>1`  and adding `0` convert `NULL` fields

```
csvjoin -H -I file* | awk -F"," 'NR>1{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf ("%s ", $i+0); print""}'
```

Which gets you to where you want to be

```
1 1 2 2 2 3 4 5 
1 1 2 2 2 3 4 5 
1 1 0 0 0 3 0 5 
0 0 0 0 0 3 0 5 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5
```

Alternatively a pure `awk` version assuming that the number of fields is constant in each file

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {mx[FNR][nf+i]=$i}}
  ENDFILE{nf+=NF; nor=(nor<FNR)?FNR:nor}
  END{for (i=1;i<=nor;i++) {for (j=1;j<=nf;j++) printf ("%s ", mx[i][j]+0); print ""}}' file*
```

which simply loads values from each file into an array `mx[][]`

```
{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {mx[FNR][nf+i]=$i}}
```

at the end of each file, move the column index `nf` right by the number of fields in the file `NF` and take the greater of either the current number of records `NR` or the last matrix size `nor`

```
ENDFILE{nf+=NF; nor=(nor<FNR)?FNR:nor}
```

And at the end just iterate over the matrix dimensions and convert `NULL` values

```
END{for (i=1;i<=nor;i++) {for (j=1;j<=nf;j++) printf ("$s ", mx[i][j]+0); print ""}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
% stitch --autocol --ofs="\\t" one two three four five
1       1       2       2       2       3       4       5
1       1       2       2       2       3       4       5
1       1                               3               5
                                        3               5
                                                        5
```

As `paste` is close but not quite there. Set `--ofs=,` and `--ifs=,` for actual CSV data, though be aware that split-at-comma is a really bad CSV parser.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions);
GetOptions(
  'autocol|ac' => \my $Flag_AutoCol,
  'ifs=s'      => \my $Flag_IFS,
  'ofs=s'      => \my $Flag_OFS,
  'rs=s'       => \my $Flag_RS,
) or exit 64;

$Flag_IFS //= ' ';
$Flag_OFS //= ' ';
$Flag_RS  //= '\n';

$Flag_IFS =~ s/(\\t)/qq!"$1"!/eeg;
$Flag_OFS =~ s/(\\[nrt])/qq!"$1"!/eeg;
$Flag_RS =~ s/(\\[nrt])/qq!"$1"!/eeg;

my @fhs;
my $seen_stdin = 0;

for my $arg (@ARGV) {
  # "file" (no spec) or "file:" (no spec but colon) or "file:spec"
  # where no spec means "print all columns and do not preserve column
  # positions as will not try to guess that"
  my ( $file, $spec );
  if ( $arg =~ m/^([^:]+)$/ ) {
    $file = $1;
  } elsif ( $arg =~ m/^(.+):([^:]*)$/ ) {
    $file = $1;
    $spec = $2;
  }
  die "could not parse file from '$arg'\n" if !defined $file;

  my $fh;
  if ( $file eq '-' and !$seen_stdin ) {
    $fh         = \*STDIN;
    $seen_stdin = 1;
  } else {
    open $fh, '<', $file or die "could not open $file: $!\n";
  }
  push @fhs, [ $fh, defined $spec ? specify($spec) : undef ];
}

my $have_fhs = @fhs;
while ($have_fhs) {
  my $pad_col = 0;
  for my $i ( 0 .. $#fhs ) {
    if ( defined $fhs[$i]->[0] ) {
      my $line = readline $fhs[$i]->[0];
      if ( !defined $line ) {
        # EOF on an input file
        $fhs[$i]->[0] = undef;
        $have_fhs--;
        $pad_col += @{ $fhs[$i]->[1] } if defined $fhs[$i]->[1];
        next;
      }

      # Complicated due to not wanting to print the empty columns if
      # there's nothing else on the line to print (works around getting
      # an ultimate blank line that messes up the shell prompt)
      if ($pad_col) {
        print( ($Flag_OFS) x $pad_col );
        $pad_col = 0;
      }

      chomp $line;
      my @fields = split /$Flag_IFS/, $line;

      # Set field count from the first line of input (may cause
      # subsequent uninit warnings if the number of columns then drops)
      if ( $Flag_AutoCol and !defined $fhs[$i]->[1] ) {
        $fhs[$i]->[1] = [ 0 .. $#fields ];
      }

      if ( defined $fhs[$i]->[1] ) {
        print join( $Flag_OFS, @fields[ @{ $fhs[$i]->[1] } ] );
      } else {
        print join( $Flag_OFS, @fields );
      }
      print $Flag_OFS if $i != $#fhs;

    } elsif ( defined $fhs[$i]->[1] ) {
      $pad_col += @{ $fhs[$i]->[1] };
    }
  }
  print $Flag_RS if $have_fhs;
}

exit 0;

# Parse 1,2,3,5..9 type input into Perl array indices
sub specify {
  my $spec = shift;
  my @indices;

SPEC: {
    if ( $spec =~ m/\G(\d+)\.\.(\d+),?/cg ) {
      push @indices, $1 .. $2;
      redo SPEC;
    }
    if ( $spec =~ m/\G(\d+),?/cg ) {
      push @indices, $1;
      redo SPEC;
    }
    if ( $spec =~ m/\G(.)/cg ) {
      warn "unknown character '$1' in spec '$spec'\n";
      exit 65;
    }
  }

  # Assume user will use awk- or cut-like column numbers from 1, shift
  # these to perl count-from-zero internally.
  $_-- for @indices;

  return \@indices;
}

__END__
=head1 NAME

stitch - joins columns from multiple input files

=head1 SYNOPSIS

   $ cat a
   a b c
   $ cat b
   1 2 3
   4 5 6
   7 8 9
   $ stitch --ofs=\\t a:2 b:1,3
   b       1       3
           4       6
           7       9

That is, column two from the first file, and columns one and three from
the second. The range operator C<..> may also be used to select a range
of columns, e.g. C<1,4..6,8>.

=head1 DESCRIPTION

This program joins columns by line number from multiple input files.

=head1 USAGE

  $ stitch [--ac] [--ifs=s] [--ofs=s] [--rs=s] file[:spec] [file[:spec] ..]

Use C<-> to select columns from standard input; otherwise, specify files
to read input from, along with the optional column specification (by
default, all columns will be selected).

This program supports the following command line switches:

=over 4

=item B<--autocol> | B<--ac>

Set the number of columns from the first line of input seen from a
C<file> if a column specification was not provided for said C<file>.
Influences empty field padding (which only happens with a column
specification should a file run short before the others).

=item B<--ifs>=I<s>

Specify the input field separator (space by default). A C<\t> will be
expanded to the actual character:

  $ perl -E 'say join("\t", qw/a b c/)' | stitch --ifs=\\t -- -:2

Or, use a regex:

  $ perl -E 'say join("\t", qw/a b c/)' | stitch --ifs='\s+' -- -:2

=item B<--ofs>=I<s>

Output field separator (space by default). Similar expansion done as
for B<--ifs>, though also C<\n> and C<\r> are allowed.

=item B<--rs>=I<s>

Output record separator (newline by default). Expansion done as
for B<--ofs>.

=back

=head1 SECURITY

Probably should not be run under elevated privs due to user-supplied
input to the L<perlfunc/"split"> function.

Passing a user-supplied regex to L<perlfunc/"split"> might be a bit
sketchy especially if L<sudo(1)> or the like is involved. It might be
nice to have per-file IFS (so one could split on spaces on stdin, and
C<:> from C<passwd>), but that would add complications.

=head1 SEE ALSO

awk(1), comm(1), cut(1), join(1), perl(1)

=cut
```

Comment: I apologize, but I am relatively new to using linux and bash and this makes no sense to me. Is this really the easiest way to do this?

Comment: @thrig Did you write this stitch script?  If so, i suggest you add an AUTHOR and LICENSE section to the documentation.  If not, well, do the same or at least link to where you found it.